# Maintaining 'focus' on Leap Motion Python (IDLE) code execution

Tags: python, python-idle, leap-motion

When executing Leap-Motion-centric code in the Python IDLE, switching to another window makes the IDLE disregard the Leap controller and stop processing `frame`s. How can this be avoided so that, say, the Leap gestures can be used to interact with other windows?

Not really relevant, but code to reproduce this problem:

```
import Leap
from Leap import *

class FocusListener(Leap.Listener):
    def on_frame(self, controller):
        frame = controller.frame()
        print frame

def main():
    # Create a sample listener and controller
    listener = FocusListener()
    controller = Leap.Controller()

    controller.add_listener(listener)

    while (1):
        listener.on_frame(controller)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

PS: Might this have something to do with the fact that I'm 'synthetically' looping the frame with the `while`?

Comment: To downvoter: At the time of writing this, the documentation *did not correctly cover this question*. I have since submitted a report and it has been fixed. Would you please explain why the negative vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get frames while your app isn't focused, you need to set the "background frames" policy:

```
controller.set_policy_flags(Leap.Controller.POLICY_BACKGROUND_FRAMES);
```

See: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/python/api/Leap.Controller.html#Leap.Controller.set_policy_flags

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for — though with a slight edit: In Python, use `controller.set_policy_flags(Leap.Controller.POLICY_BACKGROUND_FRAMES)`.